# Trying to use the "schedule" module to automate opening a program is this possible? (Im trying to automatically log into my meeting

Tags: python, automation, schedule

```
import schedule 
import os

def start_file():
    os.startfile("C:\python\Zoom.lnk")


schedule.every().day.at("09:00").do(start_file())
```

It just opens my zoom application without it being at the proper time and it gives me the error:

```
 "File "C:\Users\Hate348\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\schedule\__init__.py", line 440, in do
    self.job_func = functools.partial(job_func, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: the first argument must be callable"
```

Comment: Is that the entire error output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `start_file()` should be `start_file` in the `do()` call:

```
import schedule
import os

def start_file():
    os.startfile(r"C:\python\Zoom.lnk")

schedule.every().day.at("09:00").do(start_file)
```

Otherwise you call `start_file()` only once, and you ask the schedule library to call the result value of that call, which is `None`, every day at 9. Calling `None` doesn't make sense, hence the exception.

Second, there has to be a loop for the scheduled jobs to actually take place:

```
import time

...

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Otherwise the script will just stop and not do anything. It's a very simple library without any external dependencies; it doesn't use the operating system's task schedulers or anything like that, so the script has to keep running for it to work.

So, in total:

```
import os
import schedule
import time

def start_file():
    os.startfile(r"C:\python\Zoom.lnk")

schedule.every().day.at("09:00").do(start_file)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

If you don't need the task to start at 9:00:00 sharp, but just around 9:00, you can also prolong the sleep to one minute and save a little bit of CPU:

```
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(60)
```

Also, I added `r` before the `"C:\python\Zoom.lnk"` string. Not because it doesn't work in this specific example (it does), but generally, without the `r`, the `\` will be an escape character in the string, and with other characters after `\`, such as `n`, you will get unwanted results. With the `r`, `\` characters are taken literally and never as escape characters. And that's what you want with backslashes in filenames, especially on Windows.